# How to maintain a test site and a live site for Wordpress development?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have to make a old Wordpress blog site responsive. I have a test site as well as a live site at the moment. I should do all the designing and development on the test site. To do this now I am going to import the live database to my test database and do all the changes there. And after done with all the changes I am going to put the test database to the live site.
But here the problem is my client needs to do all the Blog post changes to the live site and test site meanwhile the development is in progress. Please let me know if anyone know how to deal with this kind of situations?

Comment: I have lots of posts on the live site. I need to make all the posts responsive as well.

Comment: You don't have to make posts responsive. You also don't need the latest up to date db for the site to do this. You can just simply downlaod the db to your test site once. Remember, you are not making the posts responsive, but the theme. You actually just need a handfull of posts to test the responsitivity of the theme. When you're done, you can just upload the theme to the live site. No need to import and export db's

Comment: But we might need to change the posts to mach with the new format that format includes some "###" or "***" or html tags to separate the content inside the post.Therefore some kind of change is needed. Please let me know if you recommend not to do such a thing.

Comment: Why don't you just style these tags accordingly. You say you have a lot of posts, and going through them one by one and changing them will take a lot of time and effort, in which case I will say, put the live site in maintainance mode, edit the posts, and when done, make the site live again. I would really recomment to rather style these html tags that changing your posts

Comment: Thanks.. The site is a busy site my client will not allow us to put the site on maintenance mode for that. Anyhow we need to have a test site for this and test database as well. In that case The test database need to go live when the update is done.

Answer (score 0):

Create sub-domain and work on it. Your client can make changes in it, check and verify changes online so he/she do not need to wait till you complete test site in local server and upload it.

If your domain is www.mydomain.com you can create sub-domain something like www.test.mydomain.com and work on it.